# CSS dropdown menu conflict

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I recently purchased a theme but now I'm having problem with the dropdown menu. It goes under the description box.

Please check the site here when we go under the women shoes and keep the mouse on "boots" submenu goes down the content box.
http://morestore.org/

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: `z-index` is your solution, give the drop down menu a high z-index, like: `z-index:99;`.

Comment: i gave the higher z-index to dropdown but still the same

Comment: .nav ul { position:absolute; top:-999em; background-position: bottom; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index: 99; }
.

Comment: try to set smaller z-index on .description, for example 1

Comment: changed with the 5 but still the same

Comment: just set `#featured` z-index to 0 and `#header` z-index to 100, i have tested and it works, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
#featured{
    z-index:0;
}

#header{
    z-index:100;
}
```

You need to add a higher z-index to the header, so it will show upside the slider. The `z-index` css property is an effective method for overcoming many layout challenges. You can read more about it at [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)

Comment: This got automatically flagged for possible deletion as "low-quality" -- and although I reviewed it as "no, it looks good", the auto-flagger does have a point; a sentence of explanation of what this does and why would make it a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

change z-index:15 to z-index:5

in

```
.slide .description {

}
```

Comment: changed with the 5 but still the same

Comment: .slide .description { background: url(images/description-bg.png) no-repeat; width: 330px; height: 165px; position: absolute; bottom: 

-5px; right: 0px; z-index: 5; padding: 45px 60px 0px 88px; }

Comment: i'm using cache plugins, i think it's due to that

Comment: if your cms has some kind of caching you need to reset that, im still seing it as 15px.

Answer (score 0):

`#menu` should have a `z-index` higher than 15 that is set for your `.slide .description`. Change this line in your CSS file:

```
#menu{position:absolute;bottom:-103px;left:0px;background:url(images/secondary-menu.png) no-repeat;width:961px;height:98px;z-index:10;}
```

to this:

```
#menu{position:absolute;bottom:-103px;left:0px;background:url(images/secondary-menu.png) no-repeat;width:961px;height:98px;z-index:20;}
```

I've tried it in Chrome and it then works. You can put a lot higher value for z-index in case you'll be later adding other dynamic contents like your description label and they'll have z-index over the label ;)

Comment: @user1830939: you can press `ctrl`+`F5` to clear the cache ;)